# Is it possible to get the class type in a static method?

Tags: types, dart

Dart code:

```
class User() {
   static onmystatic() {
       printCurrentType(); // should print:  User
   }
}
```

Notice the `printCurrentType()` in the class `User`, is it possible to implement it? I tried `this.runtimeType` but it reminds me `this` is not in scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `onmystatic()` is static, any functions it calls must static (or a instance method of some object), so I'll assume `printCurrentType()` is also static. Since static methods can't be overridden, the type is constant and you can just write:

```dart
class User {
  static onmystatic() {
    printCurrentType();
  }

  static printCurrentType() {
    print(User);
  }
}
```

If you wanted `printCurrentType()` to be some generic method that printed the type of the containing class of any static method it was called from, well... that's a much tougher task. The easiest answer is just don't try to do that and pass the class as a parameter:

```dart
class User {
  static onmystatic() {
    printCurrentType(User);
  }
}

printCurrentType(Type type) {
  print(type);
}
```

The complicated answer is that you could throw an exception, parse the stack trace, and try to determine by some rules which class you should print. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader :)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it's impossible currently to do this without reference to the class itself.

But always there exists a non-elegant way. That is the answer to your direct question (not an indirect way).
If you want use this:

```
printCurrentType();
```

But you does not want use this:

```
printCurrentType(User);
```

Then take a look at this example:

```dart
import 'package:stack_trace/stack_trace.dart';

void main() {
  User.onmystatic();
  printCurrentType(); // should print: null
}

class User {
 static onmystatic() {
   printCurrentType(); // should print: User
   Teacher.onmystatic(); // should print: Teacher
 }
}

class Teacher {
  static onmystatic() {
    onmystatic2();
  }

  static onmystatic2() {
    printCurrentType();
  }
}

void printCurrentType() {
  print(getClass(2));
}

String getClass(int position) {
  var trace = new Trace.current();
  var frames = trace.frames;
  if(position >= frames.length) {
    return null;
  }

  var member = frames[position].member;
  var parts = member.split('.');
  if(parts.length < 2) {
    return null;
  }

  return parts[0];
}
```

---

It produce output:

```
User
Teacher
null
```

---

And there is no magic...